# bcm2835_spi_begin failed. Are you running as root?

Tags: python

I use bcm2835's mcp3008 sample program to export to .so
Then use ctypes to draw .so in python
But in the process of compiling python, the following error is thrown

```
bcm2835_spi_begin failed. Are you running as root??
```

How can I solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

The function `bcm2835_spi_begin` requires root privileges to run.

You have two choices.

1. don't use `bcm2835_spi_begin`
2. run the program with root privileges

Comment: Is there any way to enter root without using command-line interface?
In the case of compiling with IDE, directly maintain the state of root?

Comment: You need to edit your question and show the commands you are running.

Comment: @user19104274 `Is there any way to enter root without using command-line interface?` ... please post that in a new question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions ... it is unrelated to your posted question ... it should not be answered here